# Log out using forms authentication in SP2010

Tags: forms-authentication

I have configured an intranet using Claims based authentication and an extended internet site using forms based authentication in SP 2010

All is set up and working except logging out...

I have a loginstatus control which I have placed a linkbutton inside the loggedin template.
When I click the button to log out, I have used:

```
 Session.Abandon();
        Response.Cookies.Clear();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

And a custom redirect.
~However when I get redirected back to my home page the system still says that Im logged in and I navigate around the site. How else do I force a logout?

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try this out

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/2ae9cf86-0d3e-4f28-8e8a-f5b01baf28d4

Answer (score 0):

How have you implemented the custom redirect? Is it a Response.Redirect? I can imagine that could override the clearing of the cookies in the http response.